# Where can I find out the possible environment variables for Hyperledger Fabric peer command?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

When configuring a peer node to run, there are a number of environment variables included in the sample docker-compose files. Is there somewhere that I can find them all documented?

e.g.

```
environment:
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
  - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hyperledger Fabric provides a configuration file called **core.yaml**, you can find that **inside the peer container** on folder /etc/hyperledger/fabric/

Fabric uses [Viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) as configuration framework, which provides an ability to override values of configuration files by environmental variables. Basically it initialized as following:

```
// used to prefix config keys to prevent possible collisions
viper.SetEnvPrefix("core") 

// enforces to check values configured via environmental variables first
viper.AutomaticEnv()
```

This makes viper to seek for all configuration key among environmental variables prefixed by `CORE` string.

Now if for example we take a look on [peer section](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.0/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L59) (updated) within sample config:

```
peer:            
    id: jdoe            
    networkId: dev    
    listenAddress: 0.0.0.0:7051    
    address: 0.0.0.0:7051
```

any of these value could be overridden by exporting proper environmental variable, for instance peer network id:

```
export CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=mypeerID
```

Same also works for other sections, for example if we would like to control logging level of different components:

```
logging:

    peer:       info
    cauthdsl:   warning
    gossip:     warning
    ledger:     info
    msp:        warning
    policies:   warning
    grpc: error
```

To make msp component to log debug level message we need to export following variable:

```
export PEER_LOGGING_MSP=debug
```

**Please note that this will take effect only if exported prior to peer start.**

Answer (score 3):

Hyperledger Fabric provides a [sample configuration file](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/sampleconfig/core.yaml) that basically includes all the possible properties for the `peer` component. Of course, you will need to convert the yaml properties to the corresponding environment variable name using the formula:

```
foo:

    bar: baz
```

becomes `CORE_FOO_BAR=baz`

The same applies to the `orderer` component, which has it's own [sample configuration file](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/sampleconfig/orderer.yaml).

Comment: That link is now dead. New one: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/sampleconfig/core.yaml

Comment: what is t the format for arrays?? `externalBuilders: []`

Comment: Comma separated values

Answer (score 1):

environment are actually items in core.yaml,replace "." with "_"

Answer (score 1):

Some of the environment variables can be found at [Environment variables for the binaries](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/upgrading_your_components.html) section of the official documentation.

**peer environment variables**

```
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
```

**ordering node variables**

```
ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
```